# Romper la cadena en Css, Se sale del Col-md

Tags: css, angular

Tengo un row, que lo separo en columnas y cada columna lo vuelvo a separar, siempre en partes iguales

El problema es que el span *se sale fuera de sus coles* y llega hasta el otro extremo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SCSS

```
.aggrid--units--detail-child {
  .center {
    text-align: center;
  }

  span {
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
}
```

Dejo un *ejemplo* de la Estructura del html.

¿ Por qué el **word-wrap: break-word;** no me está rompiendo la palabra ? 
Gracias.

Edito para poner más información:

Esta es la salida html :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el row y dentro los coles de 3 porque voy a tener 4 cuadrados naranjas.
Dentro de cada col, de 3, está tu row para poder partirlo en 2(col-md-6)

código:

```
       let result = '<div class="row">';

        keys.forEach(key => {
          value = objects[key];
          content = value[0];
          childKey = Object.keys(content);

          result += '<div class="col-md-3 aggrid--units--detail-child">';

          childKey.forEach(childs => {
            result += '<div class="row">';
            if (childs !== 'name') {
              result += '<div class="col-md-6"><label>' + childs + '</label></div>';
            }

            switch (childs) {
              case 'a':
                result += '<div class="col-md-12 center"><strong>' + content[childs] + '</strong></div>';
                break;
              case 'b':
                result += '<div class="col-md-6"><a href="#" ><span>' + content[childs] + '</span></a></div>';
                break;
              case 'mcp':
                result += '<div class="icon col-md-6"><a href="#"><span>' + content[childs] + '</span></a></div>';
                break;
              case 'd':
                result += '<div class="avatar col-md-6"><span>' + content[childs] + '</span></div>';
                break;
              default:
                result += '<div class="col-md-6"><span>' + content[childs] + '</span></div>';
            }
            result += '</div>';
          });
          result += '</div>';
        });
        result += '</div>';
```

Comment: ¿estas utilizando bootstrap?

Comment: si claro , ya viene todo por defecto de bootstrap

Comment: ¿el texto que se desborda es una sola palabra muy larga o es un frase muy larga? Por favor pon un ejemplo con textos y sus etiquetas html correspondientes que puedan reproducir el problema para poder llegar a una solución

Comment: El, texto es algo como " C/ de la gominola, casa de la piruleta, barrio tal y pascual etc... " es una frase muy larga que se sale fuera de su Col-md y fuera de su row ... y llega a solapar el otro cuadrado naranja  como se ve en la imagen.

Comment: he puesto una imagen de la salida de la ejecución  y el código

Answer (score 0):

Mira el detalle esta en los cols internos, la forma correcta debería ser:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- Row principal -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row"> <!-- Row interno 1 -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    label
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    span con frase muy larga.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row"> <!-- Row interno 2 -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    label que es solapado
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    span  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: he puesto una imagen de la salida de la ejecución  y el código